# Save the same file to multiple db entries in Django

Tags: django

In my Django app the user fills in a form and uploads a file. I need to create multiple db entries, but they all should reference the same file. In other words, if there's 10 objects that need to be created, I don't want to save the uploaded file 10 times to my storage backend. I want to save the file once and then each db entry should reference the same file.

Below is what I currently have, but it creates the file multiple times

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
    my_file = models.FileField()


class BatchTradeForm(forms.Form):
    price = forms.FloatField()
    my_file = forms.FileField()

    def create(self):
        new_items = []
        for x in range(10):
            entry = MyModel(**self.cleaned_data)
            new_items.append(entry)
        MyModel.objects.bulk_create(new_items)

class MyView(FormView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.create()
```

I'm guessing I need to save the file manually first to my storage backend and then save the reference some how, but I'm sure there must be a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with. Wondering if there's any downside to this approach since I'm manually saving the file first?

```
my_file = self.cleaned_data.pop('my_file', None)
if my_file:
    p = "path/to/{0}".format(my_file.name)
    path = default_storage.save(p, my_file)

new_items = []
for x in range(10):
    entry = MyModel(**self.cleaned_data)
    if my_file:
        entry.my_file = path
    new_items.append(entry)
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(new_items)
```